# Is $\sqrt x$ different from $x^\frac12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Background**

I've learned that $\sqrt x$ for $x > 0$ represents the *principal square root* of $x$, which means that it yields the *positive* square root.

**Question**

Does this transfer when we consider $x^\frac12$? We often use $\sqrt x = x^\frac12$ for various reasons, but does the property of only yielding positive results apply also to $x^\frac12$?

Comment: I remember that when I took complex variables there was a difference betweet $\sqrt x$ and $x^{1/2}.$ One of them was the principal value and the other was a multivalued function, but I don't remember which was which.

Comment: No. In general for a element $x$, $x^{1/2}$ denotes every element $y$ such that $y^2=x$. The usual way to work with this is to choose one of them and give it a name.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, they mean the same thing. Otherwise functions like $\exp x$ would cease to be well defined at $\exp \frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: @bof The multivalued function probably was $x^{1/2}$. I was about to say in addition to my last comment that when one works with square roots it is common to makke some convention; the $\sqrt{z}$ for the principal root foor example.

Comment: @Jonh: No. In general $x^{1/2}$ has a single value, unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I dont think the exponential function would have any trouble treating $x^{1/2}$ as a multivalued function. You'd just have to say $(e^x)^{1/2}=\pm e^{x/2}$.

Comment: @user21820 Then my answer would be the same as the one given by Hurkil although yes, with real numbers definitely its more common to talk about $x^{1/2}$ as the positivw root

Comment: @Jonh You're right. I found my old textbook (Churchill &  Brown); $z^{1/n}$ is the set of all $n^{\text{th}}$ roots and $\sqrt[n]z$ is the principal value.

Comment: @Jonh: Yes one has to figure out the convention used. The thing is that even in algebra or field theory, we use "$x^{1/2}$" and "$\sqrt{x}$" both to refer to some single square-root, even if we can't specify which. This is so that we can still meaningfully say things like "the solution is $\frac12 ( \pm \sqrt{x} \pm \sqrt{y} \pm \sqrt{z} )$ where an odd number of the signs chosen are positive".

Comment: @bof: Generic (but single) $n$-th root, or the whole set of $n$-th roots?

Comment: @bof: Okay I guess in complex analysis it can be convenient to have a notation for the whole set, though I've not seen this frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a notational convention. Different people and different textbooks may do different things.

If the precise detail matters, you have to infer what the convention is from context (or if you're lucky, you know because the speaker/author explicitly said so).